# Access gives an input box for a query with a specific WHERE clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm troubleshooting a database developed by someone else in my organization. 
I have an SQL Statement with a legitimate

```
SELECT Statement...FROM My_Download WHERE Age>=75;
```

Why would this prompt me for input when I run this SELECT Statement rather than displaying the results?

Comment: What happens when you change the where clause to `WHERE My_Download.Age>=75`?  Also, what prompt text do you see in the input dialog?

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I tried it and I still get the input box.

Comment: However I just did some further analysis on the table being queried (not of my design).  I found that there are normal ages (ie: 23, 45, 98, 8) and also ages like this: 5Y 4M, 4Y 3M.  I think this is where my problem is coming from - bad user input data.  Wondering if I can append this column of the table to remove set values like 5Y 4M = 5.  Could I do a LEFT(Column_Name, 1) ??

Comment: Unless, of course, it's good user input data with a poor application design...

Comment: LOL, yes this could also be the case. I guess this is the joys of cleaning up someone else's mess!

Comment: Is it possible to fix the data in in this column of the table via an Append Script? or by other means?

Comment: The Input box is titled: Enter Parameter Value, and the text above the text box in it reads "Meditech.Pt_Age"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the query can't find all the requested fields in the source `My_Download.`  Try rebuilding the query and you should spot the problem.  Also, check the properties (a panel visible when in Design or SQL view).  If you find an extraneous Filter or Order string, remove it.

Comment: Is it possible Delete records from the query if the value contains text? I'm thinking something like using an INSTR function to search for "M" and if the value is not 0 then delete it from the query results. Is that something I could do?

Comment: I don't want to sound discouraging, but I presume you want to do no harm.  Fixing someone else's work can be hazardous and IMO it requires plenty more skill than building an application from scratch.  (In fact it's made many a career in Access.)  That said, yes, it should be easy to remove the non-numeric values -- there are many approaches.

Comment: A general term for what lies ahead is `data normalization`.  A practical advice would be that round-trips to Excel are often convenient (assuming the datasets aren't enormous).

Comment: I've added this query and it seems to remove the data                    DELETE FROM Meditech_Download
WHERE instr( Meditech_Download.Pt_Age, "M") <> 0
 OR instr( Meditech_Download.Pt_Age, "D") <> 0

Comment: Okay, so following the principle of "do no harm", you could prefer to keep the records and use an update query to convert an entry like `5Y 4M` to `5.`  But if what you did is helping the cause, then well done!

Comment: Thanks @Smandoli, I was actually just thinking the same thing. It doesn't seem to like the "Deleted" rows.  I was thinking exactly what you're saying. This is what I'm trying but it doesn't like my UPDATE statement                   UPDATE Meditech_Download
IF (INSTR( Meditech_Download.Pt_Age, "D") <> 0)
 SET Meditech_Download.Pt_Age = 1
ELSIF (INSTR( Meditech_Download.Pt_Age, "M") <> 0)
 SET Meditech_Download.Pt_Age = LEFT(Meditech_Download.Pt_Age,1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69630/discussion-between-smandoli-and-jasonr).